# Translate hierarchical result set to custom object using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchical result set like so:

### [image]

Then I have a custom object as such:

```
public class AuthorizedEntity
{
    public Departments Department { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public List<AuthController> Controllers = new List<AuthController>();        
}

public class AuthController
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<AuthAction> Actions = new List<AuthAction>();
}

public class AuthAction
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> Methods = new List<string>();
}
```

Would it be possible to convert the following data into the respective object? In this particular case, the username is justinfarrugia, Controller = StocktakeController, Actions = Permissions with Methods = Edit Permissions and Set Permissions and Action = StockEvaluation with Method = Update Measurements.

I am looking for the most efficient solution.

I have tried this but it doesn't get me to the desired outcome:

```
ObjectResult<SP_GetPrivilegesByUsername_Result> lstAuthorizedUsersRaw = dbsp.SP_GetPrivilegesByUsername(inUsername.Trim());
        lstAuthorizedUsersRaw.GroupBy(p => p.Cntrollers_Name).ToList().ForEach(r =>
        {
            authEntity.Controllers.Add(new AuthController()
            {
                Name = r.Key,
                Actions = new List<AuthAction>() {
                                                    new AuthAction() {
                                                                        Name = r.ToList().Select(q => q.HMVAct_Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                                        Methods = r.ToList().Select(w => w.HMVMethd_Name).ToList()

                                                                     }
                                                 }
            });
        });
```

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is wrong with converting data? Do you have error?

Comment: edited with what i achieved so far... ideally I don't get normal nested foreach loops. I want an efficient solution to analyze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed second grouping - when you select actions from the controller group:

```
var lstAuthorizedUsersRaw = dbsp.SP_GetPrivilegesByUsername(inUsername.Trim());

authEntity.Controllers = lstAuthorizedUsersRaw
      .GroupBy(p => p.Cntrollers_Name)
      .Select(controllerGroup => new AuthController {
         Name = controllerGroup.Key,
         Actions = controllerGroup
                    .GroupBy(p => p.HMVAct_Name) // here
                    .Select(actionGroup => new AuthAction {
                        Name = actionGroup.Key,
                        Methods = actionGroup.Select(pu => p.HMVMethd_Name).ToList()
                    }).ToList()
      }).ToList();
```

Comment: i believe you need to add .ToList after the actionGroup as that way you are querying it more than once... other than that, great answer. Thanks a lot. Will test and mark as accepted.

Comment: @JustinFarrugia `actionGroup` is enumerated only once here, so there is no need to dump anything to list

Comment: Right, for some odd reason first time I ran it, it gave out that "more than once" exception for me. Guess it was a matter of re-building. Thanks again Sergey